"Unexpected extra operators after address" on terraform import
I have this configuration in my terraform module named cluster:
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "eks_cluster_https" {
  for_each                 = toset(var.cidr_blocks)
  description              = "Allow access to cluster"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.eks-cluster.id
  cidr_ipv4                = each.key
  from_port                = 443
  ip_protocol              = "tcp"
  to_port                  = 443
}

In the variables file, the two cidr blocks are set as (I made these up for security reasons):
cidr_blocks = ["15.0.0.0/8", "120.61.0.0/16"]

These two security group rules already exist in the AWS account. I want to import them into Terraform. I use this command to import the first one:
terraform import 'cluster.aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule.eks_cluster_https["15.0.0.0/8"]' sgr-0bdc5cc08c70f13c3

But when I run this command, I get the following error:
│ Error: Invalid address
│ 
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: cluster.aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule.eks_cluster_https["15.0.0.0/8"]
│ 
│ Unexpected extra operators after address.

I can't figure out what's wrong. I tried multiple variations of single and double quotes and escaping the quotes. What is wrong with this command?

Turns out that the problem was not in the extra operators after the address, but in missing module path segment at the beginning of the resource path. Terraform just gave a misleading error. The correct command was:
terraform import -var-file file.tfvars 'module.cluster.aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule.eks_cluster_https["15.0.0.0/8"]' sgr-0bdc5cc08c70f13c3

